# A problem dealing with homeomorphism .

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Are the two metric spaces $C[0,1]$ under the uniform metric and  $(0,1)$ under the standard metric, homeomorphic ???

Actually, I was thinking about this problem during proving  path-connectedness of  $C[0,1]$.

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ I thought  the other way, what if I could disprove the statement ???
First of all, $card(C[0,1]) = card((0,1))  = 2^{\aleph_0}$ .

Secondly, both are seperable, the former is due to Stone-Weierstrass theorem  and the latter due to $\mathbb Q \cap (0,1)$ .

Thirdly, neither is totally bounded, the former one has a subset of all constant functions of positive integers $\{1,2,3,4,....\}$ and the latter one due to non-compactness .
Then, I can't find an way to disprove the statement .

Now, I am thinking to prove the statement true by considering the fact of decimal representation of each point in $(0,1)$ but I don't find any assignment, even at least for continuity .

Now, I need serious help !!!

Comment: Given any $x\in (0,1),$ $(0,1)\setminus \{x\}$ is not path connected. Can you show this is false for $C[0,1]?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove a point from $(0,1)$, it becomes disconnected. This doesn't hold for $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Sir, I have already mentioned that I want to prove the path-connectedness of $C[0,1]$, so isn't there any other way to disprove the statement ????

Comment: Path-connectedness is trivial: if $f,g\in C[0,1]$, then $\lambda\mapsto(1-\lambda)f+\lambda g$ is a path from $f$ to $g$.

Comment: Sir, are $\mathbb R^2$ and $C[0,1]$ homeomorphic ??? Removing countably many points from both of them makes them still path-connected ???

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: Okay, Sir, thanks a lot !!!